# Logging OSGi via JMX or other way

Tags: logging, osgi, jmx

I’m a beginner with the technologies OSGi and JMX, so I have some questions and I hope to have answers.

I want to recover the OSGi Log object for display logs on my console eclipse and then display them on a jsp page.

Haw can I access to Log OSGi bundle via the JMX’ Object MBeanServerConnection?

Haw can I have LogEntry, ServiceReference  and BundleContext?

Is there another way to logging OSGi with a distant Object?

Thanks,

Néjib.

Answer (score 0):

From within OSGi, find the LogReader service, it will allow you to read the log entries of the OSGi system. Still, I do not understand your other use cases; what is the relationship between the JSP pages and the OSGi system?

Comment: Thanks for your speed answer.
I will display and monitoring the loggings OSGi via the web. So, I use for this struts and the JSP pages.

Comment: In a bundle activator, set up a ServiceTracker that tracks the LogReader service. From your JSP fetch the LogReader and use it.

Comment: Hi Tassos,

Perhaps this is obvious to you but
honestly I can not find the
Logreader service. Can you
help me with a concrete example.

Thanks,

Néjib.

Comment: Hi, 

The solution is with Http Service

Thanks

Comment: Hi, for the gory details, see the Log Service Specification in the OSGi Service Platform Service Compendium (download it for free from http://www.osgi.org/Download/Release4V42), section 101.4, page 22-850.